# Laravel- Query to get parent and all the possible children

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, multi-level

I have 2 tables with following structure

```
categories
id | name      |
1  | Grocery   |
2  | Beverages |
3  | Tea       |

category_to_category
id | cat_id | parent_id |
1  | 1      | null      |
2  | 2      | 1         |
3  | 3      | 2         |
```

I am looking for a way to get all the parents and their children and then sub children in an array. Hierarchy can be unlimited.
Is there any other way instead of doing loops till `n` ?

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352689/php-recursively-get-children-of-parent)

Comment: It depends. In laravel probably you have to use loops or recursion. If you want to do this in MySQL and you have MySQL v8 that supports recursive CTEs, then you can achieve the expected output with an sql query. The latter would make it a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need this package. No need to use recursion

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

// Accessing ancestors

```
$node->ancestors;
```

// Accessing descendants

```
$node->descendants;
```

So easy to resolve problem